# Check if PhoneGap app is installed

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Please can you help with the below?

> 1. The user goes to http://m.somedomain.com
> 2. Does the user have the native PhoneGap app installed?
>      a.  Yes… open the native app
>      b.  No…. stay on http://m.somedomain.com

I know I can do the following but wondered if there was another way:

```
setTimeout(function ()
    { window.location = "STAY ON APP"; }
, 25);

window.location = "myApp://";
```

Ps. This needs to work for both iOS and Android.

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to use intents on android and url scheme for iOS.

Comment: I have done this to get **myapp://** working but this doesn't check whether or not the app is installed. Can you provide more information?

Comment: On iOS you can use the app store banner.  If it is installed it will allow you to open the app, if it is not installed, it will provide a link to download from the apple app store. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html